# Istallshield LE writing GUID instead of Product Verison in the MSI

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, installshield

I can't find how make Installshield LE (vs2015) to put the Product Version in the MSI file properties. The Version is set in "General Information" page. But it is not written it in the MSI properties, instead a GUID is written.

For Setup.exe works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

MSI, as per documentation, does not offer the possibility to set the Product Version.

So other fields have to be used like "Tag", "Comment", etc. to set a readable version of the setup in the properties of the MSI file.